# Swift OperationQueue time to start next operation

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue

I have a collection of tasks which operate asynchronously and have inter dependencies. Right now all this is managed with custom code and I would like to use an OperationQueue instead. However, timing performance is very critical.

With the current implementation, when one task finishes it immediately calls the needed code to start the next task. So the time involved is just calling a function. The existing tasks are fairly minimal with some being asynchronous and some being a single function call.

What is the time involved from when one operation finishes and the next operation begins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have questions like this, you might want to just measure it. Signposts and Points of Interest (using Instruments to “profile” the app) are a great way of measuring performance. Thus:

```
import os.signpost

let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: "Operations", category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

And:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

var id = OSSignpostID(log: pointsOfInterest)
queue.addOperation {
    os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Operation", signpostID: id)
}
for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
    queue.addOperation {
        os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Operation", signpostID: id)
        id = OSSignpostID(log: pointsOfInterest)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Operation", signpostID: id)
    }
}
queue.addOperation {
    os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Operation", signpostID: id)
}
```

I personally make sure I let the app reach quiescence before doing these tests, usually by just delaying the routine by a few seconds, so it reduces standard app startup overhead that might otherwise alter the results. I also do many iterations of whatever I’m benchmarking in order to capture a more representative set of results.

Profiling that with Instruments’ Points of Interest tool can take this set of results and summarize them for us. For example, on iOS simulator running on my MacBook Pro, it reported:

> Min: 31.69 µs 
>   Avg: 74.70 µs 
>   StdDev: 24.05 µs 
>   Max: 154.10 µs

On my iPhone XS Max:

> Min: 44.92 µs 
>   Average: 125.78 µs 
>   StdDev: 43.61 µs 
>   Max: 446.88 µs

Your mileage may vary, but it illustrates, in rough orders of magnitude, the sort of overhead that it entails. Bottom line, the overhead is negligible enough for most use-cases.

If you have other scenarios you want to test, feel free. Hopefully this illustrates how you can use Points of Interest tool in Instruments to measure performance. For more information, see [Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/).

Comment: FWIW, I repeated this benchmark using serial dispatch queue, and the results were comparable (which makes sense, given that operation queues are built on top of dispatch queues). Maybe that will allay your concerns re operation queue “overhead”.

Answer (score 0):

> **What is the time involved from when one operation finishes and the
>   next operation begins?**

The next operation starts almost immediately. This time is so small that you can ignore it.

> **Is there any other overheard to using Operation Queues?**

`OperationQueue` is a very effective solution.

You can control performance by setting properties:

- [qualityOfService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1417919-qualityofservice): The default service level to apply to operations executed using the queue.
- [maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount): The maximum number of queued operations that can execute at the same time.

If the operations depend on each other, remember to set this relationship for them

- [addDependency(_ op: Operation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1412859-adddependency): Makes the receiver dependent on the completion of the specified operation.